# Build New Dataframe with Grouped Ratios from Existing Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, group-by, calculation

I have a Dataframe with the following columns ("User", "ProdCode","Sentiment", "Review") where the "ProdCode" contains Product codes, and the "Sentiment" contains values of 0, 1, 2, and the "Review" contains a string text review.  See example below:

```
User    ProdCode  Sentiment  Review
User1   X1        0          [string]
User2   X1        0          [string]
User3   X1        2          [string]
User4   X2        1          [string]
User5   X2        2          [string]
User6   X2        1          [string]
User7   X3        2          [string]
User8   X3        2          [string]
```

I'm trying to create a DataFrame that groups the "ProdCode" and shows 3 ratios:

1) Number of rows where Sentiment = 0 / Total Num of Reviews for the Prod Code

2) Number of rows where Sentiment = 1 / Total Num of Reviews for the Prod Code

3) Number of rows where Sentiment = 2 / Total Num of Reviews for the Prod Code

Looking something like this:

```
ProdCode  SentimentRatio0  SentimentRatio1  SentimentRatio2
X1        .67              0                .33                
X2        0                .33              .67
X3        0                0                1.00
```

I have tried many unsuccessful creations of the new fields in the Dataframe, code below.

```
DFF['sent0_ratio'] = [(count(DFF[sentiment])) if x == "0" else "0" for x in DFF.sentiment]
```

OR

```
DFF['sent0_ratio'] = sum(DFF['sentiment' if x == 0 for x in DFF.sentiment].groupby(DFF['ProdCode']).mean(), 2)
```

Neither of these are working as expected.  I don't even think I'm close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new dataframe by joining two separate dataframe group results. The first will groupby "ProdCode" and "Sentiment", the second will group by "ProdCode" to get the total count per "ProdCode". Join on "ProdCode" and limit columns to "Review" and Review_r"

```
df1 = (
    df.groupby(["ProdCode", "Sentiment"])
    .count()
    .join(df.groupby("ProdCode").count(), "ProdCode", rsuffix="_r")
)[['Review', 'Review_r']]

df1

                    Review  Review_r
ProdCode Sentiment                  
X1       0               2         3
         2               1         3
X2       1               2         3
         2               1         3
X3       2               2         2
```

Calculate the "Review"/"Review_r", reset the index to columns, and pivot for final result.

```
df1['result'] = df1['Review']/df1['Review_r']
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df1 = df1.pivot("ProdCode", 'Sentiment','result').fillna(0)
```

Final DataFrame:

```
Sentiment         0         1         2
ProdCode                               
X1         0.666667  0.000000  0.333333
X2         0.000000  0.666667  0.333333
X3         0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks @run-out! One follow up:  how do I convert the new columns to %?

Comment: One additional follow up-- The goal of this is for me to take this data frame and create a new data frame only including the ProdCode and all Reviews for that Prod Code, only selecting ProdCode's where my new '0' column > .50, for example, how would I go about creating that?  I am trying to get a list of Prods and Reviews in a dataframe that had the lowest sentiment ratio.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by convert to percentages, but maybe you mean to make it look like 66%? In this case just df1 = df * 100, then df1.astype('int'), make a new dataframe if you wish to preserve the values in the first df

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your second question, but in any event, sounds like it should be new question. Cheers,

Comment: Thanks @run-out!  I have posted another question if you would like to look at it! "Filter one DataFrame by unique values in another DataFrame"

Comment: When I display columns on the new data frame, it only shows '0','1','2'.  Why is ProdCode not included in the columns?  I need it so that I can use it to join on a new dataframe.

Comment: You have to reset the origianl df everytime you run it. Try running it from the original definition of the first dataframe. Maybe also clear your kernals if you are on Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind looking at my other question?  The only response thus far seems to not be working.